# Redirect homepage only regardless of the slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect the homepage of the old site `site1.com]` to the homepage of the new site `site2.com]`, excluding subpages and parameters.

Redirects like:

site1.com - > site2.com redirect

site1.com/ - > site2.com redirect

site1.com/subpage/ - no redirect

site1.com/index.php?id= - no redirect

site1.com/?parameter= - no redirect

Comment: Hello Paweł Burzyński, greetings!! could you please do let us know if our answers have helped you, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. Basically looks for if either query string is empty or request uri is empty then redirect to other domain site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://site2.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rule in your `site1/.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ https://site2.com/ [L,R=301]
```